# Counting all words in multiple files and outputting each count along with its filename

Tags: unix, word-count

I am struggling with the following issue. I have a Unix directory containing ~ 60K files and I would like to be able to count all the words in each file and output a list with each count along with its corresponding filename.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a job for [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) and [`wc`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -w {} \;
```

This will `find` all files (`-type f`) in the current working directory (`.`), without recursing into subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`) and for each result will execute (`-exec [...] \;`) `wc -w` passing that filename (`{}`) as an argument.

`wc` prints the number of newlines, words, and bytes in files by default, `-w` specifies it should just print the word-count.

Comment: Nice. What's the `\;` for?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: The `;` tells `find` where the `-exec` ends and the ```\``` prevents the shell interpreting the `;`.

Comment: For bonus points, here's how you can get a "Top 10" by word-count: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | sort -rn | awk '{ printf "At number %2d is %s with %d words.\n", NR, $2, $1 } NR == 10 { exit } '`

Answer (score 0):

Few more handy commands to get result from current folder

To get word in all files with file type java

```
find . -name '*.java' | xargs grep 'word'
```

To get word in all files

```
find . -type f | xargs grep 'word'
```